# How to upload community posts to youtube with its api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

i want to auto upload yt community posts

Ive looked through the documents but I've been having hard time finding anything about it
if you can, linking the relevant page on this would make it easier

Comment: Duplicated with [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75943196).